# Writing my own Methods - SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, methods, sprite-kit

I often find myself repeating code, so I would like to create a method to handle it and cut out a lot of repetition. I struggle to understand methods, so could someone suggest how i would create a custom method to handle the repeated code in the touchesBegan method.

Thanks

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

for (vLineName in vLineArray) {

    NSString *value = [vLineArray objectForKey:vLineName];
    SKAction *changeLineToDark = [SKAction setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"darkTexture.png"]];


    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKSpriteNode *box = (SKSpriteNode *)[self childNodeWithName:value];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(box.frame, touchPoint)) {
            [box runAction:changeLineToDark];
            box.zPosition = 2;
            NSLog (@"Just Touched %@", vLineName);
        }
     }
}

for (hLineName in hLineArray) {

    NSString *value = [hLineArray objectForKey:hLineName];
    SKAction *changeLineToDark = [SKAction setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"darkTexture.png"]];


    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKSpriteNode *box = (SKSpriteNode *)[self childNodeWithName:value];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(box.frame, touchPoint)) {
            [box runAction:changeLineToDark];
            box.zPosition = 2;
            NSLog (@"Just Touched %@", hLineName);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the code from touchesBegan:withEvent: method like:

```
-(void)handleTouch:(NSSet *)touches
{
    for (vLineName in vLineArray) {

    NSString *value = [vLineArray objectForKey:vLineName];
    SKAction *changeLineToDark = [SKAction setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"darkTexture.png"]];


    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKSpriteNode *box = (SKSpriteNode *)[self childNodeWithName:value];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(box.frame, touchPoint)) {
            [box runAction:changeLineToDark];
            box.zPosition = 2;
            NSLog (@"Just Touched %@", vLineName);
        }
     }
}

for (hLineName in hLineArray) {

    NSString *value = [hLineArray objectForKey:hLineName];
    SKAction *changeLineToDark = [SKAction setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"darkTexture.png"]];


    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKSpriteNode *box = (SKSpriteNode *)[self childNodeWithName:value];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(box.frame, touchPoint)) {
            [box runAction:changeLineToDark];
            box.zPosition = 2;
            NSLog (@"Just Touched %@", hLineName);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And every time the screen was touched you can call it:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self handleTouch:touches];
}
```